# Auth module for Kohana

Tags: php, kohana

I have a project with the php framework Kohana. Currently, I'm trying to add the authentification on my website. I saw the Auth module to add this functionality. I have some problems about it, I can't connect any users, so I have some questions.

First, I have an existing database with a "users" table. I want to use this database and this table to connect my users. But, what I understood is that I need to use the given database "auth-schema-mysql.sql". Is there a way in the config files to change the source of the database.

I have an other question about the place of the code. I made a template with the connection form (where the user will insert his data). Then, I have a Controller with the function `action_index`. Should I add the auth programm in this function or add an other `action_something`.

This is the code that I added, but doesn't work.

```
    $post = $this->request->post();

     $success = Auth::instance()->login($post['login'],$post['password']);
     if($success)
    {
        $view = View::factory('environment');
    }else
    {}
```

Do you have any suggestion or example to help me please ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

[**Here**](http://jdstraughan.com/post/auth-module-for-kohana-31-using-orm-driver/) you will find a great tutorial how to use Kohana auth module with ORM driver. This tutorial contains register user and login forms examples.

If you will use auth module with ORM driver (which I recommend) then you need to put database configuration file in *application/config/database.php*. [**Here**](https://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/database/config) you have more details.

This is an example of auth module configuration file with ORM driver. You should name it **auth.php** and also put in *application/config/* directory.

```
return array(

    'driver'       => 'ORM',
    'hash_method'  => 'sha1',
    'hash_key'     => 'some_hash_key',
    'lifetime'     => 1209600,
    'session_key'  => 'auth_user',

    // Username/password combinations for the Auth File driver
    'users' => array(
    ),

);
```

Comment: Did you have time to look at tutorial from my answer. Did it help :)?

Comment: It helped, I'm using the code in the turorial but I still have some error with the request. He's trying to check at the field "username" but in my database, it's called "login" and I don't know where to change this parameter :/